# How create cron task programatically with parameters from custom module

Tags: magento2

Can I add a new cron task programmatically with parameters? For example, the product ID will act as a parameter and the timestamp - the second parameter.

And the second question is, how can I delete the cron task programmatically?

Comment: https://techurbane.com/how-to-create-cron-job-in-magento-2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is decorated as helper just for show how you can work with Cron in Magento.

Magento doesn't have something like parameters for task and you need to extend `cron_schedule` with additional field

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/db_schema.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="cron_schedule" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Cron Schedule">
        <column xsi:type="text" name="arguments" nullable="true" comment="Serialized Arguments"/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Declaration of cron job

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/crontab.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default">
        <job name="acme_stackexchange_demo" instance="Acme\StackExchange\Cron\Demo" method="execute">
            <schedule>0 * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Example cron job and how you can get arguments

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Cron/Demo.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Cron;

use Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;

class Demo
{
    protected SerializerInterface $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        SerializerInterface $serializer
    ) {
        $this->serializer = $serializer;
    }

    public function execute(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $arguments = [];
        if ($schedule->getArguments()) {
            $arguments = $this->serializer->unserialize($schedule->getArguments());
        }

        // your custom logic here
    }
}
```

Cron Helper

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Helper/Cron.php**

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Helper;

use Magento\Cron\Model\ResourceModel\Schedule\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Cron\Model\Schedule;
use Magento\Cron\Model\ScheduleFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\SerializerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\DateTime;

class Cron extends AbstractHelper
{
    private const DATE_FORMAT = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';

    protected ScheduleFactory     $scheduleFactory;
    protected CollectionFactory   $collectionFactory;
    protected DateTime            $dateTime;
    protected SerializerInterface $serializer;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ScheduleFactory $scheduleFactory,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        DateTime $dateTime,
        SerializerInterface $serializer
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->scheduleFactory   = $scheduleFactory;
        $this->collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->dateTime          = $dateTime;
        $this->serializer        = $serializer;
    }

    public function create(string $jobCode, int $scheduleAt = null, array $arguments = []): void
    {
        $schedule = $this->scheduleFactory->create()
            ->setJobCode($jobCode)
            ->setStatus(Schedule::STATUS_PENDING)
            ->setCreatedAt(date(self::DATE_FORMAT, $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp()))
            ->setScheduledAt(date(self::DATE_FORMAT, $scheduleAt ?? $this->dateTime->gmtTimestamp()));

        if ($arguments) {
            $schedule->setArguments($this->serializer->serialize($arguments));
        }

        $schedule->save();
    }

    /**
     * @return Schedule[]
     */
    public function search(array $filters): array
    {
        $collection = $this->collectionFactory->create();
        foreach ($filters as $field => $condition) {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($field, $condition);
        }

        return $collection->getItems();
    }

    public function delete(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $schedule->delete();
    }
}
```

Usage Example

```php
$cronHelper = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(\Acme\StackExchange\Helper\Cron::class);

// create task and schedule right now
$cronHelper->create('acme_stackexchange_demo', null, ['key' => 'value']);

// search tasks by parameters
$tasks = $cronHelper->search([
    'job_code' => 'acme_stackexchange_demo',
]);

foreach ($tasks as $task) {
    if ($task->getStatus() === Schedule::STATUS_SUCCESS) {
        // delete task
        $cronHelper->delete($task);
    }
}
```